# Render a React element inside a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

OK I'm trying to pass a component inside an object I use as a parameters to an action I'm triggering.

```
this.context.alt.actions.notificationActions.logMessage({
  component: <ModalLayoutEditorComments subscription="pop-up" contextualClass="info" callback={this._submitCaisseChangeAction} />,
  subscription: 'pop-up',
});
```

Inside the target component I receive the object as props with the component which is now React Element.

[image: React element inside object]

Now I would to know how I can convert this React element inside another React component if possible?

```
  render() {
      const Component = this.props.notifications[0].component;

      return (
        <div>
          {Component}
        </div>
      );
  }
```

Comment: Your `render` method looks fine - here is an example of rendering an element passed as props: https://jsfiddle.net/txqo702m/1/

Comment: Using ReactDOM.render inside another React component is OK? I tried with React.cloneElement without luck.

Comment: You are not calling `ReactDOM.render` inside a Component? Component `render` methods build a tree of React elements, which is ultimately turned into a tree of DOM elements by `ReactDOM.render` at the root of your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error I was getting was the following

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

I was getting undefined because the mistake I made was I was not exporting the component using `export default ModalLayoutEditorComments`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `render` logic is OK. It looks like you are using the wrong prop:

```
render() {    
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.notifications[0].component}
    </div>
  );
}
```

As an aside, `component` is quite a confusing property name. The object is a React element, which is a [description of a Component instance](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html#elements-describe-the-tree).

Comment: You'll need to be more specific? What is the error? rendering elements passed as props is a common React pattern (e.g. `{children}`). Does  https://jsfiddle.net/txqo702m/1/ work for you?

Comment: sorry for the delay the was I was getting undefined so the mistake I made was I was not exporting the component using export default ModalLayoutEditorComments.